# Django serve index.html from dist folder generated by webpack and vue

Tags: django, heroku, webpack, vue.js

I'm using Vue + webpack with a Django backend for my webapp and I need to be able to serve files from the dist folder from Django when the user hits the root url '/'. The dist folder containing the static files from Vue + webpack has already been created, and I just need to know how to serve those files from Django. I disabled collectstatic on Heroku because all my files will be served from dist folder that was not generated by django.

I'm able to serve index.html from the dist folder but not the js and css files in there. The error i'm getting is /static/js/main.js not found

Here's what I have so far, but none of my attempts are working. I need some way to configure Django urlpatterns to serve the static files in the dist folder

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../dist')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../dist')
STATIC_URL = '/dist/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../dist'),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG is False:
    urlpatterns += url(
urlpatterns += url(r'^$', generic.TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

dist/

```
 - index.html
 - static
    - js
        - main.js
    - css
        - main.css
```

Comment: Why don't you use TEMPLATE_DIR to render html, what I believe STATIC_* shall be used for static content settings.

Comment: Follow the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/ for setting up templating in Django and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/ for serving static content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django development cannot find third party script in node\_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246491/django-development-cannot-find-third-party-script-in-node-modules)

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that? it's still not working and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: This is a shot in the dark before I try to do this in heroku myself, but I see you're setting `STATIC_URL` as `'/dist/'`, what happens if you try to access your static files using that root? So `[your.app.domain]/dist/static/js/main.js`

Comment: nope still getting 404 not found :(